# Calling a back end URL using javascript channel API

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine

Handler Implementation

```
class TestHandler(RequestHandler, Jinja2Mixin):
 def get(self):
    channel_id = str(random.randint(1, 10000)) + str(datetime.now())
    chat_token = channel.create_channel(channel_id)
    context = {'channel_id': channel_id, 'chat_token': chat_token}
    return self.render_response('test.html', **context)

 def post(self):
    channel_id = str(random.randint(1, 10000)) + str(datetime.now())
    chat_token = channel.create_channel(channel_id)
    context = {'channel_id': channel_id, 'chat_token': chat_token}
    return self.render_response('test.html', **context)
```

HTML Implementation

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/static/js/backend.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
    <form method="post" id="testform" name="testform">
        <br><label name="channel_id" id="channel_id">{{channel_id}}</label>
        <br><label name="chat_token" id="channel_id">{{chat_token}}</label>
        <input type="submit" id="btnsubmit" class="btnsubmit" name="btnsubmit" value="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

jQuery implementation

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var token =$('#channel_id').val()
    alert(token)

    var channel = new goog.appengine.Channel(token);
    var socket = channel.open();
    socket.onopen = onOpened;

    onOpened = function() {
        connected = true;
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST','/dashboard/', true);
        xhr.send();
    };

    socket.onmessage = onMessage;
    socket.onerror = onError;
    socket.onclose = onClose;
 });
```

I want to call a Back end handler. I do not know how to do it. This is what i have done . Can anyone give a help ?

Comment: The Channel API is mostly unrelated to this question, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You access a back end with a url like http://instance.backend.appid.appspot.com (see [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/overview.html#Addressing_Backends)). Since you can't make an XHR to a page like this from an page rendered on http://appid.appspot.com, you have basically two options:

You can marshal the request to your backend via a servlet on your frontend. So you could do something like:

```
class MarshalServlet(RequestHandler):
  """ This class is part of your frontend. """
  def post(self, instance, backend):
    # generate an urlfetch request to http[s]?://instance.backend.appid.appspot.com
    # and return its result.
    # (left as an exercise for the reader)

# add a "dashboard" handler to your frontend application.
app = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/dashboard/', MarshalServlet),
                               # other servlets etc.
                             ], debug=True)
```

Or you could use JSONP to do a cross-domain request, which is easy with [jQuery's getJSON method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/):

```
$.getJSON("http://instance.backend.appid.appspot.com/dashboard/", function() {
  alert("success");
});
```

It's not clear to me what your /dashboard/ handler does, so I'm not sure if it can/should return JSON or if you care about the headers and so on.

Also note that using the getJSON method won't send along cookies, but you could do that with a marshaling servlet.